# How can I recursively and asyncronously build a tree of unknown size?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, sequelize.js

I'm trying to retrieve my comments on a given post for my website but I am unable to build up the nested comments because of the asynchronous nature of `node.js`.

```
getBlock([], function(){});    

function getBlock(comments, callback) {
    comments.forEach(function(comment) {
        getChildComments(comment, function(err, children) {
            if (children) {
                getBlock(children, callback);
            }
            comment.Comments = children;

            /* not sure how to decide when to be done?*/
            callback(null, comments);
        });
    });
}
```

The above code works fine for synchronous code but does not work for asynchronous because I cannot tell when `comments` contains all of the data to return to the browser.

I tried to keep track of the recursive calls and end when there were 0 calls left but that was buggy and sometimes would return early depending on the tree structure.

Comment: Hello Jack, wouldn't it be better to have structure in the DB:
idComment, idParentComment, idArticle, userName, userComment, dateAdd

or something like that... and than just select all comments for given idArticle using just one DB query and than sort it just once?

Comment: @JanJůna That is what I was trying to do eariler although I think I'm limited by my ORM. The comments are nested and comments can have their own comments. I am using sequelize and postgresql

Comment: You can do raw query in sequelize - see this:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/

Lets imagine that your page will be requested by 100 users and you will run all these recursive queries one hundred times (for every client) which will drain resources of your DB..

Comment: You really should try to query this data in one or two trips rather than recursively looping. For a really big comment thread this could be a huge performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a count of the work still to do, and when it reaches zero, you call the caller's callback function. Each instance of an executing function in the recursion tree, will define its own callback, so that only the call made by the top level instance will call the callback in the first statement (outside of the function body):

```
function getBlock(comments, callback) {
    if (!comments || !comments.length) {
        // Nothing to do, call back synchronously
        callback(comments);
        return;
    }
    var leftOver = comments.length;
    comments.forEach(function(comment) {
        getChildComments(comment, function(err, children) {
            comment.Comments = children;
            // provide custom callback:
            getBlock(children, function () {
                // only call parent's callback when all is done here:
                if (--leftOver === 0) callback(comments);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Unlike your example code, the above must not be called with an empty array, but with an array of comment objects of which you want to retrieve the hierarchy below them. To get everything, you would pass an array with one dummy comment object, which would have an undefined `id` (to be matched with the parentId references of comments that have no parents). Something like this:

```
getBlock([container], function(){
    console.log(container);
});
```

Below is a working implementation, which uses mock data and `setTimeout` to simulate the asynchronous `getChildComments`:

```js
function Comment(id, text, parentId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.parentId = parentId;
}

var mockData = [
    new Comment(1, "Michal Jackson died today"),
    new Comment(2, "How did he die?", 1),
    new Comment(3, "His doctor gave him too much of the white stuff", 2),
    new Comment(4, "He died in his sleep", 2),
    new Comment(5, "Oh my god, this can't be true!?", 1),
    new Comment(6, "He will be greatly missed", 1),
    new Comment(7, "I am working in my garden"),
    new Comment(8, "Happy birthday, friend!"),
    new Comment(9, "Thank you!", 8),   
];

function getChildComments(parentComment, callback) {
    // Mock asynchronous implementation, for testing the rest of the code
    setTimeout(function () {
        var children = mockData.filter(function (comment) {
            return comment.parentId === parentComment.id;
        });
        callback(null, children); 
    }, 0);
}

var container = new Comment(); // dummy node to collect complete hierarchy into
getBlock([container], function(){
    console.log(container);
});

function getBlock(comments, callback) {
    if (!comments || !comments.length) {
        // Nothing to do, call back synchronously
        callback(comments);
        return;
    }
    var leftOver = comments.length;
    comments.forEach(function(comment) {
        getChildComments(comment, function(err, children) {
            comment.Comments = children;
            // provide custom callback:
            getBlock(children, function () {
                // only call parent's callback when all is done here:
                if (--leftOver === 0) callback(comments);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

#### Performance considerations

The above is a direct answer to *"How can I recursively and asynchronously build a tree of unknown size"*, but it might not be the most efficient way to get the final result.

You get your data from a Postgres database, and probably perform a query for each call to *getChildComments*: this might take a relatively long time to complete, and puts quite a load on your database engine.

It might be more efficient to perform a single query to retrieve the whole hierarchy of comments.

Comment: After considering your performance considerations section I going to write my own custom query. Thanks for your help.